# Car won't start when it's a little cold outside

Tags: battery, mercedes-benz

I have a Mercedes A140 (2001) and the engine won't crank if the battery is "cold" - around 10 Celsius. Yes, the car starts just fine after I've heated the battery indoors. I've tried other batteries and the problem remains. Any advice on what could be faulty would be very appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a failing battery, replace it.

Answer (score 1):

If a known good tested battery is installed and the problem persists, the problem is probably going to be found in the battery cables or connections, the starter or the starter relay.